# How do I remove a load management device?

Tags: electrical

I bought this house a few years ago. It has a load management device on my air conditioner and hot water tank. I want the device removed. How do I go about it?

Comment: More information about the arrangement would help greatly. Your question is rather vague. Please take the [tour].

Comment: Generally, those are "sold" by the power company to shut off your appliances at their convenience for a discount on your rates. You probably need to contact the PoCo to get them removed.

Answer (score 2):

Removing them should be as easy as disconnecting the wires and unscrewing the devices with the power being off.

But, big but, they are usually not used for the fun of having them.

Your power company might have installed them and own them.  Might be under contract/discount pricing plan/required for your service.

You also might have a too small electric service that cannot handle AC, hot water, cooking supper all at the same time without tripping the main breaker.

If main breaker trips too often it can break and you are without power till it is replaced.  Unless the electrician is right there and can pull the meter and replace it.